# OneDrive Saver Api (Multiple Files Upload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, onedrive

```
 var MyFiles = [];
  if (val == "Address") {
                        MyFiles.push({ 'file': 'http://----/Content/File/Addresses.xlsx', 'fileName': 'Addresses.xlsx' });
                    }
                    if (val == "DebitDetail") {
                        MyFiles.push({ 'file': 'http://----/Content/File/DebitDetails.xlsx', 'fileName': 'DebitDetails.xlsx' });
                    }
                    if (val == "AddressAssociated") {
                        MyFiles.push({ 'file': 'http://----/Content/File/AddressAssociatedCompanies.xlsx', 'fileName': 'AddressAssociatedCompanies.xlsx' });
                    }
                    if (val == "DebitDetailAssociated") {
                        MyFiles.push({ 'file': 'http://----/Content/File/DebitDetailsAssociatedCompanies.xlsx', 'fileName': 'DebitDetailsAssociatedCompanies.xlsx' });
                    }



  var saverOptions = {
            file: myFiles,
            success: function () {
                // upload is complete
            },
            progress: function (p) {
                // upload is progressing
            },
            cancel: function () {
                // upload was cancelled
            },
            error: function (e) {
                // an error occured
            }
        };

        OneDrive.save(saverOptions);
```

I have used the above code for DropBox and it works well because it takes an array of objects but i cant find solution for OneDrive.com!
Below documentation only shows how to upload a single file using URL. but i want to upload multiple files.

The Format From The OneDrive Site

```
var saverOptions = {
  file: "inputFile",
  fileName: 'file.txt',
  success: function(){
    // upload is complete
  },
  progress: function(p) {
    // upload is progressing
  },
  cancel: function(){
    // upload was cancelled
  },
  error: function(e) {
    // an error occured
  }
}
```

https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/javascript-picker-saver.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the OneDrive Saver only lets you upload one file at a time. Depending on the type of app you're writing, it may be an option to go directly to the OneDrive API. Here's info about [uploading files with the API](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload.htm).